# How to populate cell in spreadsheet from selection made in listbox in userform

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, userform

I am completely new in this and got stuck on something that sounds like a simple thing.
I created simple user form, where assemblers will enter one of the items as a search criteria.  The listbox is then populated with all results from original spreadsheet showing the location of that part.  Assembler will then select one item that they need to pick and click the button "pick".
What that will do is enter the date in "PickDate" in spreadsheet.  And that is where I am stuck.
My thinking was to select the row in the spreadsheet identical to the selected row in listbox, and then create address of the cell using that row and column.  But it doesn't work.  Tried several things that I could find on internet and nothing works.  At one point I had date being entered in correct column, but not correct row.  Unfortunately, cannot remember what that code was.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.  [userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8x58.png)  [spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2N7Y.png)

```
Private Sub PickBtn_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
  If Cells(i, 2) = Results.List(Results.ListIndex) Then
    Rows(i).Select

    .Range(Selection, 7).Value = Date
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[Entry form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hidbm.png)

```
Private Sub CancelJob_Click()
'Close EntryForm form
   Unload EntryForm

'Show InitialForm form
  InitialForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Empty all fields
JobBox.Value = ""
Customer.Value = ""
Location.Value = ""
Rack.Value = ""
    
'Fill combo box with product types
 With ProductCombo
    .AddItem "Channel Letter Faces"
    .AddItem "Channel Letter Backers"
    .AddItem "Routed Aluminum Panels"
    .AddItem "Routed ACM Panels"
End With

'Set focus on Work order TextBox
JobBox.SetFocus
End Sub


Private Sub SubmitJob_Click()
'Make fields mandatory
If JobBox.Value = "" Or ProductCombo.Value = "" Or Rack.Value = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Cannot submit.  Please fill the mandatory fields.", 
 vbQuestion + vbOKOnly) <> vbOKOnly Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

End If

'Start transfering process
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    
    'Transfer information to the table
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Date 'Auto populate 1st column with submission date
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = JobBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Customer.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Location.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = ProductCombo.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Rack.Value
        
'Save workbook after transfer of data
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Close EntryForm
Unload Me

'Quit application so that others can use it
'Application.Quit
End Sub
```

This is complete code for this search part of the userform that I cannot
figure out (I was playing with the code for "submit" button that I am stuck).  Maybe it will help for troubleshooting:

```
Private Sub ClearForm(Except As String)

' Clears the list box and text boxes EXCEPT the text box
' currently having data entered into it

Select Case Except

    Case "Job"
        FormEvents = False
        Customer.Value = ""
        Location.Value = ""
        Results.Clear
        FormEvents = True

    Case "Customer"
        FormEvents = False
        Job.Value = ""
        Location.Value = ""
        Results.Clear
        FormEvents = True

    Case "Location"
        FormEvents = False
        Job.Value = ""
        Customer.Value = ""
        Results.Clear
        FormEvents = True
    
    Case Else
        FormEvents = False
        Job.Value = ""
        Customer.Value = ""
        Location.Value = ""
        Results.Clear
        FormEvents = True
        
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub ClearBtn_Click()

ClearForm ("")

End Sub

Private Sub Job_Change()

If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("Job")

End Sub

Private Sub Customer_Change()

If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("Customer")

End Sub

Private Sub Location_Change()

If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("Location")

End Sub

Private Sub PickBtn_Click()
Dim i As Integer


Sheet1.Activate

For i = 1 To Range("A10000").End(xlUp).row
If Cells(i, 2) = Results.List(Results.ListIndex) Then
Rows(i).Select

Me.Range("Selection:G").Value = Date
    
  
End If
Next i


End Sub







Private Sub SearchBtn_Click()

Dim SearchTerm As String
Dim SearchColumn As String
Dim RecordRange As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim FirstCell As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer

' Display an error if no search term is entered
If Job.Value = "" And Customer.Value = "" And Location.Value = "" Then

    MsgBox "No search term specified", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub

End If

' Work out what is being searched for
If Job.Value <> "" Then

    SearchTerm = Job.Value
    SearchColumn = "Job"
    
End If

If Customer.Value <> "" Then

    SearchTerm = Customer.Value
    SearchColumn = "Customer"
    
End If

If Location.Value <> "" Then

    SearchTerm = Location.Value
    SearchColumn = "Location"
    
End If


Results.Clear

    ' Only search in the relevant table column i.e. if somone is 
searching Location
    ' only search in the Location column
    With Range("Table1[" & SearchColumn & "]")

        ' Find the first match
        Set RecordRange = .Find(SearchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues)

        ' If a match has been found
        If Not RecordRange Is Nothing Then

            FirstAddress = RecordRange.Address
            RowCount = 0

            Do
            
                ' Set the first cell in the row of the matching value
                Set FirstCell = Range("B" & RecordRange.row)
                
                ' Add matching record to List Box
                Results.AddItem
                Results.List(RowCount, 0) = FirstCell(1, 1)
                Results.List(RowCount, 1) = FirstCell(1, 2)
                Results.List(RowCount, 2) = FirstCell(1, 3)
                Results.List(RowCount, 3) = FirstCell(1, 4)
                Results.List(RowCount, 4) = FirstCell(1, 5)
                Results.List(RowCount, 5) = FirstCell(1, 7)
                RowCount = RowCount + 1
                
                ' Look for next match
                Set RecordRange = .FindNext(RecordRange)

                ' When no further matches are found, exit the sub
                If RecordRange Is Nothing Then

                    Exit Sub

                End If

            ' Keep looking while unique matches are found
            Loop While RecordRange.Address <> FirstAddress

        Else
        
            ' If you get here, no matches were found
            Results.AddItem
            Results.List(RowCount, 0) = "Nothing Found"
        
        End If

    End With

End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

FormEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Add another column to your listbox to reference the row number of the spreadsheet that the data came from. If you post the code that populates the list box I can help further.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for helping.  I attached Entry form screenshot and code for it as asked.  In Spreadsheet I have the formula that says if "PickDate" is empty, set "Picked" cell to Not Picked.  If the PickDate column has date, set to Picked.  Last two columns I didn't include in my codes for userforms.

Comment: Where is the code that populates the list box ? I assume that is something like `SearchBtn_Click()`.

Comment: I had to add it to my original post, so you can see above attached Entry form screen shot, and underneath the complete code for that box.  Starting with Sub for CancelJob_click, then initializing and then Submit button click for transferring to the spreadsheet.  The workflow for this is that one department in my company makes these parts and store them on the rack.  Then final assembly picks up those parts as per job order and finishes with the manufacturing.  So, entry form is filled by the first operator on the router.

Comment: I might misunderstood what are you looking for.  I added complete code for this userform.  The code for Pick button is little different here because of me trying things and playing with it on Friday.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another column in the list box to hold the row number.

```vb
Results.List(RowCount, 6) = FirstCell.Row
```

And then code becomes

```vb
Private Sub PickBtn_Click()

    Dim r as long
    r = Results.List(Results.ListIndex,6)
    Range(r, 7).Value = Date

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot.  It didn't work with Range (giving me "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.  But I changed into Cells(r, 7).Value = Date and it looks like it works.  Again, Thanks a million.  :o)

Comment: @LiloK Yes my mistake .